# Hand-drawn 3 Illustrator help

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have made the following using Adobe Illustrator, the 3 was made bespoke from my hand writing (which is quite poor!) I want the curve of the 3 to be more symmetrical & perfect... How can I do this?

[image: from illustrator]

Answer (score 2):

You could overlay a circle on the bottom portion of the three. Make sure the stroke is the width you're looking for. Expand the object.

Then use the shapebuilder tool to add and subtract pieces of the circle and the three until you get the symmetrical look that you're going for. If there are any rough edges, use the smooth or pen tools to even them out.

[image]